# Find the decomposition of the following matrix into two level unitary matrices

Tags: matrix-representation, unitarity

Find the decomposition of the following matrix into two level unitary matrices:

$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & i & -1 & -i\\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -i & -1 & i\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Quantum Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform#Definition) and the Wiki page provides a generic decomposition:

[image]

Can you find your two qubit version?